# powershell if file doesnt exist log string to file

Tags: powershell, file-exists, logfile

I have many file paths stored in a DB. I need to check if the files actually exist. I've done this before but lost the script for it and need some help.

I put all the paths in a text file and want to loop over them, and check if they exist. if they don't exist, I want to put the nonexistent path in a log file.

Something like this:

```
# ! equals -not

$log = "e:\pshell\notExists.log"
$log | out-file $log

$list = Get-Content "e:\pshell\files.txt"

Foreach ($file in $list)
{
  CHECK IF FILE EXISTS
  IF IT DOESNT then Write-Output $file
}
```

little help?

Answer (score 4):

test-path?

```
$log = "e:\pshell\notExists.log" $log | out-file $log

$list = Get-Content "e:\pshell\files.txt"

Foreach ($file in $list) 
{ 
   If (!(test-path $file))
   {
      Write-Output $file
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you inputfile is one filepath per line, try:

```
$log = "e:\pshell\notExists.log"

Get-Content "e:\pshell\files.txt" | Where-Object {
    #Keep only paths that does not exists
    !(Test-Path $_)
} | Set-Content $log
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$log = "e:\pshell\notExists.log" 

Get-Content "e:\pshell\files.txt" |
where {!(test-path $_)} |
add-content $log
```